# Is there a regression method for fitting general N-order polynomials of two or more variables?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I would like to fit a general N-order polynomial of two or more variables. For example, consider (for reference) the general second-order polynomial in two variables $x$ and $y$:

$$\beta_{00}+\beta_{01}y^1+\beta_{02}y^2+\beta_{10}x+\beta_{11}xy+\beta_{12}xy^2+\beta_{20}x^2+\beta_{21}x^2y+\beta_{22}x^2y^2.$$

Another example could be the general N-order polynomial in two variables $x$ and $y$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N}\sum_{m=0}^{N}\beta_{nm}x^ny^m$$

I know that there is an extension of linear regression named Multiple Linear Regression, but is there a regression method for fitting general N-order polynomials of two or more variables?

Comment: Yes: it's called multiple linear regression :-). Please forgive me for copying the comment I left with the duplicate of this question that you deleted, because it is just as apt as before: "Many readers will be wondering why you haven't just fit this (routine) model using ordinary least squares on your favorite statistical computing platform, so we suspect you must have tried that and run into some kind of trouble. What exactly was the problem?"

Comment: I believe this case is covered by multiple linear regression. Just use the combinations of x and y as the predictor variables and zeros as the dependent variables.

Comment: @Daniel I believe it is understood in this question that there is a response variable that is supposed to be fit with the polynomial and that corresponding values of $x$ and $y$ are available. To what, then, are you referring by "zeros"? And could you explain why you refer to "dependent variables" in the plural? Perhaps there are multiple valid interpretations of this question that we need to disambiguate.

Comment: Since x and y values are known, one could fit the straight forward linear regression:

$0 = \beta_{00} + \beta_{10}x + \beta_{01}y + \beta_{20}x^2 + \beta_{11}xy + \beta_{02}y^2 + \dots$

Comment: The 'least squares' being minimized will have a different meaning than the usual case and the result may be useless for prediction of y given x.

Comment: @DanielJohnson you are right about the least squares, but the method is called General Linear Least Squares.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the edition and the comments, I wouldn't have found the answer without them.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you: your interpretation seems to be that a relationship only between $x$ and $y$ is being sought and there is no third variable. Although using $0$ as a response is a clever idea, it is doubtful that it is a good statistical procedure, so some justification of your recommendation (preferably with a successful example of its application) would be welcome. Gorayni, generalized least squares will not apply to Daniel's interpretation nor is it necessary in my interpretation. But *which interpretation is the one you have in mind?*

Comment: @ Daniel Johnson You cannot have an "all-zero" dependent variable - the OLS estimator would just produce a vector of zeros as estimates.  (cc:@whuber)

Comment: @whuber is right about using 0 as a response, please Daniel  check the link of my answer.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos this is correct, sorry. I suppose you could use $y = \beta_{00} + \beta_{10}x + \beta_{20}x^2 + \beta_{11}xy + \beta_{02}y^2 + \dots$ to get a 'fit', but again it would likely not be a statistically sound procedure as whuber pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following two expressions:

$$z_i = \sum_{n=0}^{N}\sum_{m=0}^{N}\beta_{nm}x_i^ny_i^m+AE_i,\qquad i=1,...,T > N^2$$

where $AE_i$ stands for "approximation error",

and

$$z_i = \sum_{n=0}^{N}\sum_{m=0}^{N}\beta_{nm}x_i^ny_i^m +u_i\;,\qquad E(u_i\mid X,Y) = 0\;,  i=1,...,T > N^2$$

where $u_i$ is a random variable with the stated properties, and $\{X,Y\}$ is to be understood as containing the series of $(x,y)$ but also of their powers etc.

If we write them down in full, in both cases we have a $T\times N^2$ system of equations that is *linear in the $N^2$ unknown coefficients*.

What is their difference?
The first is NOT a stochastic specification, but a *mathematical approximation* specification: we want to express the values of $Z$ as a function of a $N$-order polynomial in $X,Y$. We do not make any assumptions as to whether any of $Z, X,Y$ are random or not, we just treat them as three $T\times 1$ column vectors containing numbers, vectors which we want to relate in the way the specification expresses.

The second is a *stochastic* specification, where even if we assume that the $X,Y$ are deterministic vectors, the existence of $U$ which is *assumed* random, makes $Z$ a random variable.

But in both cases, since a priori we have $T > N^2$, each system will be *overidentified* as a matter of basic mathematical results. This means that in either case we cannot find values for the unknown coefficients such that the vectors containing the terms $AE_i$ and $u_i$ respectively will be zero vectors.
Since we cannot achieve the ideal, it is natural to attempt to somehow *optimize* the way we will arrive at some values for the unknown coefficients.

In the mathematical approximation specification, our motive is to achieve the "best" approximation, and that's it. Intuitively "best approximation" translates into "minimum approximation error". But trying to minimize the sum of $AE_i$'s would be misleading, since $AE_i$'s can be both positive and negative, and so, in a simple sum  they will tend to offset each other. The next natural step is to consider the sum of absolute values, which is indeed the most intuitive concept. But the absolute value is a nasty beast to manipulate mathematically, and this is how we arrived at the concept of minimizing the *sum of squares* -and the "least-squares" methodology was born (centuries ago). In the context of the mathematical approximation specification, this leads us to apply the "General Linear Least Squares"  which minimize $\sum_{i=1}^TAE^2_i$. Note again that the crucial matter in order to apply the least-squares methodology is whether the unknown coefficients (the subject of calculation/estimation) have a pure linear relationship with $Z$. We don't care whether the elements of $X,Y$ are squared, square-rooted or whatever.

In the stochastic specification we postulate a *deterministic* relation between $Z$ on the one hand and $X,Y$ on the other, but one which is "disturbed" by unpredictable (hence "random") factors, embodied in $U$. We also assume (or hope), that "on average" these disturbances cancel out, hence the expectational assumption on $U$. So here, we assume that *there exists a TRUE value of the coefficients beforehand* describing the relationship, and we want to *estimate* this true value. Due to the contamination of the data by the disturbances, we cannot uncover the exact true values... the next best thing is for our estimates to be *as close as possible* to these true values... and one way to do that is to apply the least-squares methodology, which has strong intuitive power, in a "multiple linear regression" setting, as it is called in statistics.

To summarize: in the mathematical approximation specification, we care directly about the magnitude of the approximation error. In the stochastic specification, we care predominantly about the magnitude of the distance between the coefficient estimates and their true values, but we "discover" that this may be represented as isomorphic to the magnitude of "residual" which is the statistical term for the approximation error.

So we end up applying the same mathematical methodology on the same data, which means that the least-squares coefficient estimates in these two systems of equations *will be exactly the same*. 
But the *goal and motive* is different, and also, the subsequent *interpretation* of the results is different.

In the first case, the mathematical approximation is just that: we have *described* $Z$ as an approximate function of $X,Y$. Without further assumptions or arguments, we cannot use this results to say something about another data set containing values of $Z,X,Y$.

In the second case, the stochastic specification is endowed from the beginning with the assumption that there is a general relation between the $Z,X,Y$ variables, one that goes beyond the specific sets of numbers we have available. So the results we obtain can in prnciple be validly used to talk about this general relation that holds between these *variables*, and not just for the specific sample.

So if one *starts* from "I want to fit a $N$-order polynomial" one is closer to the spirit of the mathematical approximation method, because one does not argue as to *why* the $Z$ variable should somehow relate to the $X,Y$ set (including powers etc). We need a pre-estimation argument that involves either causality or at least *association* between $Z$ and $X,Y$ in order to be in the spirit of the stochastic specification.

Answer (score 0):

The regression method for fitting general N-order polynomials of two or more variables is the **General Linear Least Squares**. Each monomial of the polynomial represents a basis function of the design matrix. For more details check [General Linear Least Squares Technique](http://w3eos.whoi.edu/12.747/notes/lect03/l03s03.html)

Comment: "General Linear Least Squares" is a non-stochastic description of Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) in a standard statistical multiple regression model. The critical _linearity_ characteristic in OLS has always been about the _unknown coefficients_, not about the regressors (regressors that are included in the design matrix). The clarification question remains: is both $x$ and $y$ in your polynomial considered as "independent/explanatory variables", "regressors"? Does another variable $z$ exists, non-identically zero, for which you want to fit $z = \sum_{n=0}^{N}\sum_{m=0}^{N}\beta_{nm}x^ny^m$?

Comment: Yes, I am assuming that $x$ and $y$ are independent, and that $z$ exists and is non-identically zero. I will also check the OLS, thanks @AlecosPapadopoulos

Comment: You do not have to assume independence of $x$ and $y$; even when they are, their monomials usually will not be independent. If $z$ is identically zero, OLS still works, but as @Alecos points out, the solution is not very interesting!

Comment: @ whuber I slipped into outdated and confusing terminology by using the word "independent" for the regressors as opposed to the "dependent variable". Didn't mean that they are "independent between them" of course.