# Using MLE vs. OLS

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, least-squares

When is it preferable to use Maximum Likelihood Estimation instead of Ordinary Least Squares?  What are the strengths and limitations of each?  I am trying to gather practical knowledge on where to use each in common situations.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143705/maximum-likelihood-method-vs-least-squares-method

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares), OLS is just a particular instance of MLE. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80424/sum-of-squared-difference-and-gaussian-noise-model/80564#80564) is closely related question, with a derivation of OLS in terms of MLE.

The conditional distribution corresponds to your noise model (for OLS: Gaussian and the same distribution for all inputs). There are other options (t-Student to deal with outliers, or allow the noise distribution to depend on the [input](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/downloads/Bishop-Noise-ICANN-97.pdf))

Comment: (-1) It's not true that the student $t$ can be depended upon to *deal with the outliers*. See the example [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86447/603) or chapter 2 of [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/0470010940) textbook for more explanations.

Comment: The OLS is a distance-minimizing approximation/estimation method, while ML is a "likelihood" maximization method. OLS needs no stochastic assumptions to provide his distance-minimizing solution, while ML _starts_ by assuming a joint probability density/mass function. The fact that in some circumstances the two provide the same solution, in no way does it make the one a particular instance of the other.