# Linear regression: dependent variable is conditionally normal

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, modeling

I was reading about Maximum Likelihood and linear regression and found a lot of literature saying:

> For a fixed Xi, the distribution of Yi is equal to N(f(Xi),σ2)

meaning the dependent variable is conditionally normal. But I couldn't find any explanation on why/when we do this assumption on normality. Is it done because of easiness of calculations or why do we assume that for a fixed Xi, the distribution of Yi is normal?

EDIT:

In [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/254003/82889) under Maximum Likelihood section the author writes:

> Using the model above, we can set up the likelihood of the data given
>   the parameters $\beta$ as:
>
> $$L(Y|X,\beta) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} f(y_i|x_i,\beta) $$
>
> where $f(y_i|x_i,\beta)$ is the pdf of a normal distribution with mean
>   0 and variance $\sigma^2$

Why do we state that  $f(y_i|x_i,\beta)$ is the pdf of a normal distribution in the context of linear regression, why not any another distribution? Is it because the error term has a normal distribution (∼(0,2))? Or it was stated to be normal just because it was easy to show an example?

Comment: This is assumption isn't always made, so perhaps your question ought to be rephrased as *when* (that is, under what conditions) do we assume a conditional Normal distribution?

Comment: @whuber I edited my question

Comment: SimilarsQs: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148803/how-does-linear-regression-use-the-normal-distribution/148812,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/395011/why-normality-assumption-in-linear-regression